# Time Series Analysis - for negative values?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I am trying to see some trend based on the Sales figure based on Months

```
Amount
    14997.816
    26460.718
    19607.54
    -7612.395
    78424.35
    4565.6275
    5338.02
    8650.41
    24390.235
    9691.5975
    168614.2575
    887.25
    12748.9
    7651.5315
    402818.9605
    1912.45
    113.5
    11175.6245
    23481.0465
    10052.49
    26962.1625
    56399.7825
    9751.879
    3577.967
    25698.45
    24844.565
    10339.175
    165261.7405
    460.8935
    8383.212



Date
    6/1/2010
    6/1/2010
    6/1/2010
    6/1/2010
    6/1/2010
    6/1/2010
    6/1/2010
    6/1/2010
    6/1/2010
    6/1/2010
    6/1/2010
    6/1/2010
    6/1/2010
    6/1/2010
    6/1/2010
    6/1/2010
    6/1/2010
    7/1/2010
    7/1/2010
    7/1/2010
    7/1/2010
    7/1/2010
    7/1/2010
    7/1/2010
    7/1/2010
    7/1/2010
    7/1/2010
    7/1/2010
    7/1/2010
    7/1/2010

df <- read.csv("----file path-----")
df$Date <- as.Date( df$Date, '%m/%d/%Y')
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(Date, Amount)) + geom_line()
```

I am getting plot, which doesn't resemble a typical Time-Series Plot, is it because of the negative values in the 'Amount'?

How can I plot time-series graph for the data above?

*sales amount is invoice + credit notes
 , credit notes are returned product, they carry a negative amount

Comment: What's the question?  Additionally, please format your example data so that it can be read into R.

Comment: Following @MatthewLundberg suggestion, please provide `dput(df)`

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you don't have a chart that resembles a time series is because your data doesn't resemble a time series.  It's easier to see with the base plotting function, that you have only two dates in your object:

```
plot(Amount ~ Date, data=df)
```

[image]

I am fairly sure that this isn't intentional.

`df`:

```
structure(list(Amount = c(14997.816, 26460.718, 19607.54, -7612.395, 
78424.35, 4565.6275, 5338.02, 8650.41, 24390.235, 9691.5975, 
168614.2575, 887.25, 12748.9, 7651.5315, 402818.9605, 1912.45, 
113.5, 11175.6245, 23481.0465, 10052.49, 26962.1625, 56399.7825, 
9751.879, 3577.967, 25698.45, 24844.565, 10339.175, 165261.7405, 
460.8935, 8383.212), Date = structure(c(14761, 14761, 14761, 
14761, 14761, 14761, 14761, 14761, 14761, 14761, 14761, 14761, 
14761, 14761, 14761, 14761, 14761, 14791, 14791, 14791, 14791, 
14791, 14791, 14791, 14791, 14791, 14791, 14791, 14791, 14791
), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Amount", "Date"), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = "data.frame")
```